# Which directory Jetty is supposed to be in?

Tags: java, nginx, jetty

I uploaded Jetty with

```
sudo apt-get install jetty
```

but I am not sure where it is installed.

I searched for it with `find` and it found it here: `/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/jetty`. Is it where it is supposed to be?

I am trying to find out how I can copy my `.war` file from the development machine to the server.

I am looking at this [tutorial](http://sacharya.com/nginx-proxy-to-jetty-for-java-apps/) where it says to change `.bash_profile` with `JETTY_HOME=/user/java/jetty-7.6.8/` but I don't see the directory `/user/java/` in my machine. What is the correct place to have Jetty server?

Comment: If you run `java -version` what does it say?

Comment: @thatidiotguy: This is what I get: `a@b:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed Jetty from some linux packaging product.  Each linux distro puts jetty in different places.  Sometimes in a single directory like `/opt/jetty` sometimes across multiple directories.

Since you seem to be using a debian based / `apt` / `dpkg` based distribution, this should help you figure it out.

```
$ dpkg -L jetty
```

That will just list the contents of that specific package you just installed.  From there you'll want to work your distribution specific documentation for jetty, as none of the standard documentation for jetty will apply to you.

Comment: Ok, 2 questions: Do you recommend I remove this installation and install it again? If so what is the best way to install it? Also, I see that `/webapps` is in `/var/lib/jetty/webapps`. Do you think if I copy my `.war` there it will work? Thanks, for the answer.

Comment: Consult your linux distribution specific documentation for jetty.  They have customized and tweaked Jetty so heavily to fit within their installation frameworks that [the standard documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/) will be useless to you.

Comment: ok, how can I uninstall jetty so that I can reinstall it according to instructions here http://pietervogelaar.nl/ubuntu-12-04-install-jetty-9/ Is this a good solution? Otherwise, I don't understand what "your linux distribution specific documentation for jetty" means or where it can be found.